# Getting error for macro when moving to a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Im getting a Run-time error '1004':

Select method of range class failed

This only happens when I move away from the sheet (Bet Angel) that has the macro running to another sheet. The code is below:

```
    Sub DeleteStatus()

Worksheets("Bet Angel").Range("O6:O50").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Call Start
End Sub

Sub Start()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), "DeleteStatus"
End Sub
```

I want the macro to run even if I am moving between different sheets in the workbook.

Comment: [Why are you `Select`inig to begin with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) `Worksheets("Bet Angel").Range("O6:O50").ClearContents`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are moving to another worksheets, you need to activate or select the target worksheet first.

```
Sub DeleteStatus()

Sheets("Bet Angel").Activate
Worksheets("Bet Angel").Range("O6:O50").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Call Start
End Sub

Sub Start()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), "DeleteStatus"
End Sub
```

If you want to go back to your original worksheet, you can activate it at the end of DeleteStatus()

Like this

```
Sub DeleteStatus()

Sheets("Bet Angel").Activate
Worksheets("Bet Angel").Range("O6:O50").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Call Start
Sheets("your original worksheet").Activate
End Sub
```

If you don't want to use `activate`, then you need to dim the worksheet first.

Like this

```
Sub DeleteStatus()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Bet Angel")
ws.Range("O6:O50").ClearContents
Call Start
End Sub

Sub Start()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), "DeleteStatus"
End Sub
```